# Non-GPL method of implementing MD5 hash for InputStream

Tags: java, hash, md5, md5sum

Can anyone point me in the direction of a Java-based non-GPL method for computing the MD5 hash of a file as it is streamed (as opposed to doing the whole file at once)?

Comment: Tool/librayr recommendations are off-topic on SO, but I see no reason to go outside the Java standard library here... have you looked at `MessageDigest`?

Comment: Going to check it out now, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java does this for you already, see [java.security.MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html).

You can stream data into it using the `update` methods.